# Why elif with multiple conditions not working

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to solve the firstNotRepeatingCharacter question on CodeSignal. The problem is that given a string of characters (in this case s), I need to return the first non-duplicate character. I don't understand why my code isn't working.

I'll paste the [link](https://app.codesignal.com/interview-practice/task/uX5iLwhc6L5ckSyNC/description) to the problem although you'll probably need to sign up.

```py
def solution(s):
    
    # run through all elements
    
    for i,el in enumerate(s):
        
        # helps check what's going on
        #print(i,el,s[i+1:], s[i-1::-1])
        
        # if it's the first element, only check for duplicates in characters in front of it
        # if no duplicate present, return first element
        if i == 0:
            if el not in s[i+1:]:
                return i,el
            
        # if it's not the first element, check for duplicates in characters in front of it and behind it
        # if no duplicate is present, return that element
        elif el not in ( s[i+1:] or s[i-1::-1] ):
            return i,el
        
        
    #otherwise, return '_'    
    return '_'
        
    s='habahzb'
    solution(s)
```

expected output z,
output a

I have tried:

```py
elif (el not in s[i+1:]) or (el not in s[i-1::-1]):
```

But I run into a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written your test incorrectly:

```
el not in ( s[i+1:] or s[i-1::-1] )
```

It should be

```
el not in s[i+1:] and el not in s[:i-1]
```

The condition you have basically translates to

```
el not in s[i+1:]
```

because `s[i+1:]` is a string of non-zero length and thus "truthy" so the rest of the expression is ignored (but was the wrong way of writing it anyway).